# Entity framework many to many relationship on same table with extra attribute

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following model Users(Id, Name) and Friends(User_Id, Friend_Id, date). 
My user entity:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How would I create Entity context for Friend table?

Comment: You need a friends table with Id1, Id2 in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start along these lines.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class Friend
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int User_Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int Friend_Id { get; set; }    

    public DateTime FriendshipDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User_Id")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Friend_Id")]
    public User UserFriend { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: Actually you may need to rename the Friend navigation so it does not conflict with the class name, but the fluent equivalent would be:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Friend> Friends { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
            .HasKey(f => new { f.User_Id, f.Friend_Id});

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
            .HasRequired(f => f.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.User_id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Friend>()
            .HasRequired(f => f.UserFriend)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.Friend_Id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But can you let me know how I can implement it using **modelBuilder**?

Comment: See edit. May have to rename the navigation Friend to FriendUser or similar.